# Redirect and post in opencart

Tags: php, html, opencart

I'm building an opencart module for my site and have a page that I need a 'refresh' button for and a 'continue' button, where I POST to either itself (in the case of the 'refresh' button or to bespoke2.php with the 'continue' button. I've added the controller and views below. Unfortunately when the continue button is clicked I get redirected to the correct page however the POST variables don't come with it. The refresh button works well. Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong, I've spent hours playing around with it and have searched the forum and google haven't come up with much?

This is the form.php

```
<form name="frm" method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="size_width">
<input type="submit"  name="submit1" class= "button" Value="<?=$button_continue?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" class= "button" Value="<?=$button_refresh?>" />
```

This is the controller.php

```
if (isset($this->request->post['submit1']))  {
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('module/bespoke2'));
} elseif (isset($this->request->post['submit2'])) {
$this->data['input_width'] = ($this->request->post['size_width']);
else{}
```

This is the code for controller bespoke2.php

```
$this->data['input_width'] = ($this->request->post['size_width']);
```

The redirect seems to not take the POST across? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have jquery available (which you should have with a default opencart install) you could use the following (add it to the end of the view) to update the 'url_to_submit_to' before submitting.

```
<script>
  $("input[name=submit1]").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('form[name=frm]').attr('action', '/url_to_submit_to').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've added this in, it sent the post to the next page and it's worked a treat. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think the redirect will 're-POST' the form variables. A quick fix might be to manually add the variable into the query string of the redirect.

```
if (isset($this->request->post['submit1']))  {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('module/bespoke2?size_width=' . $this->request->post['size_width']));
} elseif (isset($this->request->post['submit2'])) {
    $this->data['input_width'] = $this->request->post['size_width'];
else { }
```

then you could retrieve it in bespoke2.php as follows:

```
$this->data['input_width'] = $this->request->get['size_width'];
```

If you don't think that's particularly satisfactory I'd look into manually posting the data via ajax direct to the correct controller rather than redirecting.

Comment: The only problem, and it's a small one, is that there is quite a few post variables to add to this. I only showed one to simplify the example, so I was hoping to not have to do it manually.

Comment: .....also I have managed to POST using redirect using a temp HEADER, however this doesn't seem to want to work through Opencart.

Comment: Well you could use a foreach loop to loop through `$this->request->post` to build up the query string but I think the bottom line is you're trying to conditionally post a form to two different urls which isn't really how they're intended to work so anything you do is going to be a bit of a hack... another possibility might be to use javascript or jquery to update the action attribute of the form before submitting it so that it submits to a different url depending on which button is pressed.

Comment: I've added a new answer to show how you could use jquery to update the url the form is submitting to before the submit takes place

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart uses session data with redirects like the success messages eg.
This might work for your situation as well.

```
$this->session->data['input_width'] = $this->request->post['size_width'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Open

```
/catalog/controller/account/register.php
```

Change

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/customregister', '', 'SSL'));
```

If some time you have pass with this type

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=50', ''));
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean here, do you want me to change the system files to add in the "response->" note? If so what does  this do?